# CloudKit fetch latest changes from push notifications

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have an app which is available on multiple platforms (macOS, iOS, iPadOS, …) and my goal is to update widgets on each platform when CloudKit DB is changed without opening the app. Now, for example, if you changed something in iOS app you need to open the macOS app, wait for iCloud to sync and only then macOS widgets reflect new data.

I created subscriptions using [the guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquerysubscription). It seems to work and I receive push notifications when the data is changed in my AppDelegate.

```
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
        fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void
    ) {
        if CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo) != nil {

            ...
            let entries = container.viewContext.fetch(Entry.fetchRequest())
            var result = ... // generate widget state from entries
            ...
            UserDefaults.setValueForGroup(result, forKey: "widget_state")

            WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
        } else {
            completionHandler(.noData)
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I fetch data from `viewContext` I get the old ones. How can I fetch new data?

From what I found, I can use `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation` and somehow to fetch and apply all the changes from remote DB, but it has a massive implementation and looks like reinventing the wheel.

All the sync happens automatically if I start the app, how can I force the same behavior after receiving push notification? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how your record zone subscription is configured, but in order for your app to receive push notifications and update data in the background, you need to set `shouldSendContentAvailable` to `true`.

Here's how you do it:

```swift
    let subscription = CKRecordZoneSubscription(zoneID: yourRecordZoneId, 
                                                subscriptionID: yourSubscriptionId)
    let notificationInfo = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
    subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

    try await database.modifySubscriptions(saving: [subscription], deleting: [])
```

In the example above, I'm using Swift concurrency to update subscriptions but you could also use the `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation` operation, or the `CKDatabase.save(_:completionHandler:)` function

---

### Edit:

Just a couple more suggestions that might help you troubleshoot this issue:

1. Always call the completion handler, even when `CKNotification` is not nil. I.e.:

```
        if CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo) != nil {
            ...
            WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
            completionHandler(.newData)
        } else {
            completionHandler(.noData)
        }
```

2. If it doesn't work, try removing the didReceiveRemoteNotification completely just to ensure you are not interfering with the system's handling of APNs.
3. This one is a bit obvious but it's important to remember that push notifications won't work on simulators, so always test on an actual device.

Comment: Yes, I have `shouldSendContentAvailable = true`. According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cksubscription/notificationinfo/1515110-shouldsendcontentavailable), `The app then receives background execution time to download any data for the push notification, such as the set of changed records`.
My question is how to download new data from push notification or, if it is done automaticly, how to detect that it is done and I can fetch the latest data?